# vertical spacing in nested fraction

Tags: spacing, amsmath, fractions

I have complicated math expression:

[image]

Vertical spacing between text and fraction line is too small.
I tried to define new `\frac` command (with `amsmath` package) with adjustable vertical spaces. As you can see, the result is not satisfying:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,leqno]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{color,pifont,fontspec}
\usepackage[top=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm,left=2.54cm,right=2.54cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot,graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools,breqn,amsmath}
\usepackage[fontsize=12]{scrextend}
\usepackage{array,multirow}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\DeclareMathSizes{12}{14}{14}{10}
\newcommand{\myfrac}[3][0pt]{\genfrac{}{}{}{}{\raisebox{#1}{$#2$}}{\raisebox{-#1}{$#3$}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{dmath*}[breakdepth={0},style={\mathindent=0pt},spread={10pt}]
{n=\myfrac[3pt]{\myfrac[3pt]{0,0625N+0,0215}{2}-0,043}{\myfrac[3pt]{\myfrac[3pt]{\scriptstyle 0,0625N+0,0215}{\scriptstyle 2}-0,043}{\myfrac[3pt]{\scriptstyle N}{\scriptstyle 2}-1}+0,0215}}
\end{dmath*}
\end{document}
```

How can I enlarge verticall spacing in whole fraction?

Comment: `mathtools` loads `amsmath` (`\RequirePackage`), so it's useless to load it again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In such cases I'd add a `\mathstrut` which however is not sufficient if the fraction is part of a denominator. For this situation, `\big|` seems to do.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\qfrac}{smm}{%
  \dfrac{\IfBooleanT{#1}{\vphantom{\big|}}#2}{\mathstrut #3}%
}

\begin{document}

Without adjustment
\[
n=\frac
   {\qfrac{0{,}0625N+0{,}0215}{2}-0{,}043}
   {\qfrac
     {\qfrac{0{,}0625N+0{,}0215}{2}-0{,}043}
     {\qfrac{N}{2}-1+0{,}0215}
   }
\]

With adjustment
\[
n=\frac
   {\qfrac{0{,}0625N+0{,}0215}{2}-0{,}043}
   {\qfrac
     {\qfrac*{0{,}0625N+0{,}0215}{2}-0{,}043}
     {\qfrac*{N}{2}-1+0{,}0215}
   }
\]

\end{document}
```

The `\qfrac*` version is to be used when the fraction is in a denominator.

Note `{,}` so there's no space after the comma.

[image]

The picture seems to hint that the top minus sign next to 0,043 is not aligned with the fraction line, but it's just due to pixel rounding. Here's the detail at maximum magnification.

[image]

Comment: on my screen, the minuses aren't lined up even with the fraction bars.  is this just a consequence of pixel roundoff, or is there a structural cause?

Comment: Shouldn't the additive term `0.0215` be a part of the overall (first-level) denominator instead of the inner (second-level) denominator?

Comment: @barbarabeeton I added a detail at high magnification; it was pixel rounding when taking the snapshot.

Comment: @Mico The original input gave an error, so I tried to interpret it as best as I could. I don't think it has an impact on the method.

Answer (score 4):

Vertical spacing adjustments are unnecessary if you use the `\cfrac` machinery ("continued fractions") to typeset the complicated nested fraction expression.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,leqno]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[margin=2.54cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[fontsize=12]{scrextend}
\begin{document}
\[
n=\cfrac{\cfrac{0{,}0625N+0{,}0215}{2}-0{,}043}
        {\cfrac{\cfrac{0{,}0625N+0{,}0215}{2}-0{,}043}
               {\cfrac{N}{2}-1}
        +0{,}0215}
\]
\end{document}
```